# Copy files and folders using robocopy

Tags: robocopy, gpo

I need to copy directory from a server to the Program Files folder on desktop using local admin. This is what I have so far.

```
robocopy "server source" "C:\Program Files\Test" /MIR
```

I get the follwoing error

```
2014/05/23 17:53:04 ERROR 5 (0x00000005) Creating Destination Directory C:\Program Files\Test\
Access is denied.
```

I'm running the bat on logon via GPO.

Can someone please help me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the location to %appdata% from program files.